# clear or reset checkbox when clicking tab menu in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, tabs

i have a tab menu look like this. I want the checkbox reset when clicking another tab menu.
I updated my full php code to find easily any mistaken in the code written. 
I search stackoverflow to find about tab menu with checkbox reset solution but i got some solution and implemented those code. i failed to solve my problem. please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>event list</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('asset/css/tabcontent.css'); ?>" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/js/tabcontent.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="text-align:left">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form method="post" action="" >
                <div class="box">
                <legend>Add New Bundle</legend>
                    <div class="text_box3">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="tabs" id="tabs" data-persist="true">
                                <li class="selected"><a href="#view1" onclick="$('#second').prop('checked', false);">All Images</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#view2" onclick="$('#first').prop('checked', false);">Category</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="tabcontents">
                                <div id="view1" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
                                    <?php 
                                        foreach ($get_all_img as $row){
                                            echo '<div height="50px">
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="first" id="first">';
                                            echo '</label></div>';
                                        }                                        
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div id="view2" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
                            <?php 
                                foreach($get_everything as $tasks){
                                    //echo "<pre>";
                                    //print_r($tasks);
                                echo '<div class="cat_name">'. $tasks['name'].'</div>';
                                echo "<ul>";
                                    foreach($tasks as $task){
                                                foreach($task as $p){ 
                                                    foreach($p as $pr){ 
                                                        echo '<div height="50px">
                                                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="second" id="second">';
                                                        echo '</label></div>';              
                                                    }                        
                                                }  
                                        }echo "</ul>";
                                }
                            ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div><br>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: id is uinique so you shouldn't and it to more that one elemet and you make a loop with php that add more that one element with the same id so change id to class and change your tabs click event to `onclick="$('.second').prop('checked', false);"` , `onclick="$('.first').prop('checked', false);"`

Comment: also i update my answer if you like to check it.

Comment: yes, it's working. you gave me a magic answer. thank u so so much. i appreciate you for your best solution for me.  i am so much happy now. expecting next problem solving issue from you. stay with us. thanks again.

Comment: obviously i have no problem to accept your answer. i did it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can replace all your code with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>event list</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('asset/css/tabcontent.css'); ?>" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="text-align:left">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form method="post" action="" >
                <div class="box">
                <legend>Add New Bundle</legend>
                    <div class="text_box3">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs" id="tabs" data-persist="true">
                                <li class="selected"><a href="#view1" data-toggle="tab" onclick="$('.second').prop('checked', false);">All Images</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#view2" data-toggle="tab" onclick="$('.first').prop('checked', false);">Category</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="tabcontents tab-content">
                                <div id="view1" class="tab-pane" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
                                    <?php 
                                        foreach ($get_all_img as $row){
                                            echo '<div height="50px">
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="first" class="first">';
                                            echo '</label></div>';
                                        }                                        
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div id="view2" class="tab-pane" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
                            <?php 
                                foreach($get_everything as $tasks){
                                    //echo "<pre>";
                                    //print_r($tasks);
                                echo '<div class="cat_name">'. $tasks['name'].'</div>';
                                echo "<ul>";
                                    foreach($tasks as $task){
                                                foreach($task as $p){ 
                                                    foreach($p as $pr){ 
                                                        echo '<div height="50px">
                                                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="second" class="second">';
                                                        echo '</label></div>';              
                                                    }                        
                                                }  
                                        }echo "</ul>";
                                }
                            ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><br>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('asset/js/tabcontent.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="" >
    <div>
        <ul class="tabs" id="tabs" data-persist="true">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#view1" onclick="$('.second').prop('checked', false);">All Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#view2" onclick="$('.first').prop('checked', false);">Category</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabcontents">
            <div id="view1" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="first" class="first">
            </div>
            <div id="view2" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="second" class="second">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L71whna8/)  (i used bootstrap tabs just for styling)

external recorces added in the js fiddle (make sure that you add jquery before bootstrap js)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: yes, i want this type of example. i embaded some code from jsFiddle but could not work for me. is there any external resources to run the code correctly? if have then please suggest me.

Comment: yes in js fiddle i'm using jquery and bootstrap you can find its link in external resorses in the left side in the fiddle,if you couldn't get it tell me to add it in the answer

Comment: oh! i used jquery external link but it still didn't work.

Comment: can you update you html please or add it to another fiddle so i can check what is the problem?

Comment: ook i'm waiting

Comment: @KaziNayem for bootstrap tabs in demo add `nav nav-tabs` to the ul class attribute , `data-toggle="tab"` for your `<a>` tag ,`tab-content` class for you tabcontents div , `class="tab-pane"` for your divs width id's `view1` and `view2`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ax84wzzw/8/

```
$(function() {
  var firstCheckox = $('[name = "first"]');
  var secondCheckox = $('[name = "second"]');
  var firstTab = $("#tab1");
  var secondTab = $("#tab2");

  firstTab.click(function() {   
    firstCheckox.attr("checked", true);
    secondCheckox.attr("checked", false);
  });


  secondTab.click(function() {
    firstCheckox.attr("checked", false);
    secondCheckox.attr("checked", true);
  });
})
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: sorry, i want the example like first solution of Aya Salama. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Fine with me, whichever fits your requirements best